# How to transfer 'devicemotion' property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, devicemotion

I have a DOM element (in some cases several) that I want to move (by changing the css) when the device moves.

Now, I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
var aDOMElement = document.getElementById("someId");
aDOMElement.DeviceMotionEvent = window.DeviceMotionEvent;
aDOMElement.addEventListener('devicemotion', motionHandler, false);
```

I consider a workaround to just work with the `window` object and in the callback I handle the movements of all objects which are stored in an array.

Kind of like this:

```
function motionHandler(event) {
    for (var obj in objectList) {
        obj.move(event);
    }
}
```

However, for some odd reason, the `move` function I assigned to the object before storing it in the list is `undefined`. Explanations and/or solutions for this are welcome.

**EDIT**:

Here's how I create and add the object to the array:

```
var objectList = [];

var elem = document.createElement("div");
//add some properties
elem.id = "someId";
elem.move = specificMoveFunction;
//add it to the list
objectList[elem.id] = elem;
```

Comment: Can you show `objectList` and how you're adding objects / attaching `move`?

Comment: Also, `objectList` kind of sounds like an array, so you should be using a different iteration syntax, like `objectList.forEach(function (obj) { obj.move(event) })`

Comment: I added the requested edits.

Comment: Is `objectList` an array? `objectList = []` or an object? `objectList = {}`

Comment: Sorry, missed it. It's the former, added to the edit as well.

Comment: That's definitely why you're getting `undefined` then. Rather than do `objectList[elem.id] = elem`, do `objectList.push(elem)`, that way you can iterate over them properly, like in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you assign a property `DeviceMotionEvent` to a DOM element doesn't mean it's going to be fired... You'd have to connect the event listener on the window (where it is fired) to the event listener(s) on the DOM elements and fire them manually. You'd be better off listening on the `window`'s event and doing your DOM manipulation there.

e.g.

```
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(event) {
  var domElements = document.getElementsByClassName('could-move');
  for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) { 
    elements[i].classList.add("moved"); 
  }
});
```

where your HTML before would look like:

```
<span class="could-move">span 1</span>
<span class="could-move">span 2</span>
```

and after would look like

```
<span class="could-move moved">span 1</span>
<span class="could-move moved">span 2</span>
```

EDIT:

Actually, why do you need to set it from `window` onto the DOM element? can you not just `aDOMElement.addEventListener('devicemotion', motionHandler, false);` without `aDOMElement.DeviceMotionEvent = window.DeviceMotionEvent;`? The MDN docs don't say that this is ONLY fired on the window.

EDIT II:
the examples all show the event being fired only on the window: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/ so I still think you are better off listening only on the window and doing your work there.

Comment: You answered my first question, as is also stated here (look at target): [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/devicemotion). But I fixed my code with the suggestion of @azium.